# MSBuild ignores installed nugets (NuGet 3), fails

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I've a project with one NuGet dependency listed in a `project.json` file.
Build works fine within VS2015, also works fine through MSBuild on the same computer with VS2015. (Even in another totally unrelated directory just cloned from a remote git repo.)

However on another computer (same MSBuild version), it fails with a reference error. I read through the output and I found MSBuild doesn't launch the same `csc.exe` command in the two instances:

**Working instance:** `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\Users\tm\.nuget\packages\log4net\2.0.5\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\ImportCommon.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output EcritureCSV.cs LectureCSV.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\tm\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"`

**Failing instance:** `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\ImportCommon.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output EcritureCSV.cs LectureCSV.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\maurin\AppData\Local\Temp\4\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"`

In the second instance MSBuild doesn't pass the argument: `/reference:C:\Users\tm\.nuget\packages\log4net\2.0.5\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll` to `csc.exe` while the file exists since it has been downloaded with a `nuget restore` previously.

I've no idea why MSBuild doesn't add this argument.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

msbuild does not restore nuget packages. You must run `nuget.exe restore`

Visual Studio handles this, so building on the Visual Studio machine will work with msbuild as your build with VS has restored it already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however as mentionned, the packages were already restored with `nuget restore`.